# Copying for struct pointer to pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I was curious why some code like this gives a segfault

```
square->type=start.type
```

They are structs of the same type, square is a pointer and start isn't.  I thought that the value in start.type would be copied to the type section where square points to.

Can someone explain the reasoning behind the segfault?

Comment: square is a null pointer

Comment: It would be better if you show some more code, like context where it is used. But to have this code working `square` needs to be not NULL.

Comment: There nothing wrong with that line on its own. If it's failing it's because there's something wrong with the square pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be one of the following reasons:

1. `square` is null.
2. `square` is not null but uninitialized, means it's not pointing to a valid object.
3. `square` was deleted before executing that line, this also means it's not pointing to a valid object.
4. Something is wrong in the overloaded assignment operator of `type` (if `type` is a class/struct and it's assignment operator is overloaded).
5. `start` is a reference and was assigned by deferencing null, eg:

   ```
   Apple *apple=0; 
   Apple &start = *apple;
   ```
6. `start` is a reference to something and that something was deleted, eg:

   ```
   Apple *apple=new Apple(); 
   Apple &start = *apple;
   delete apple;
   square->type = start.type; // this line may not cause segfault but this is actually undefined behavior
   ```